# SQL Server Database Project Compare Schema ignore Sequence of Fields at same table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I have same tables at different databases, but the sequence of fields are not same.

When I compare between Servers the tables detected as different Structure, because the sequence is not same.

Can I ignore this every compare my databases?

[image: three]

Can You show me which option to click (if any)

[image]

my SSDT version:

[image: vs versionn]

Comment: SSDT is a separate product. Which version do you have? The latest stable version is 16.5.3 while the latest RC, 17.0 RC [ignores column order when publishing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2017/03/10/sql-server-data-tools-17-0-rc-and-ssdt-in-vs2017/)

Comment: Thank You @PanagiotisKanavos I use VS 2015, and I am not so sure which version I use. But I saw 2012 at some UI. I will check it later. Can the update installed in VS 2015? Maybe tomorrow I will check my version.

Comment: The RC can be installed *only* on VS 2015, not 2017. At the very least you should use [the latest GA release 16.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). SSDT is a separate product which means it is updated separately from Visual Studio itself. Updates do show up in `Extensions and Updates`. If you keep up with updates, you may have 16.5 already,

Comment: Mr. @PanagiotisKanavos I can not find SSDT 16.5.3 at download Page. I am installing SSDT using Extensions and Updates. It download small .exe then download so many files. Takes long time. Maybe vs team should provide offline installer for this. Put your comments to answer and I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of this time, "Ignore Column Order" is not an option for SSDT. It used to be present in the old VSTSDB projects, but hasn't made it back yet. I've heard that it's on its way back at some point, but you need to keep an eye on the SSDT blog to see what's coming.

Edit: Ignore Column Order is now available in the latest builds of SSDT. (noted by Mr. Green below)

Comment: Ignore column order is now available in VS2015.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2017/04/19/announcing-the-general-availability-ga-release-of-ssdt-17-0-april-2017/

Comment: Vs2022 - Ignore Column Order is also present!

Answer (score 1):

As described on [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2017/03/10/sql-server-data-tools-17-0-rc-and-ssdt-in-vs2017/), `Ignore column order` is now an option in SSDT version 17.0, which is compatible with Visual Studio 2015.

> If you’ve ever had to deal with accidental data
>   motion when putting a column in the middle of a table definition,
>   you’ll know how hard this can be to spot and manage. In this release
>   you can now check the “Ignore Column Order” option in the Advanced
>   Publish Options. This will append new columns to the end of an
>   existing table rather than altering the table structure to add the
>   column in its listed position.

You can find the setting by going into the `Advanced...` button section of your publish profile, as well as in the `Advanced...` button section of the database project properties' `Debug` tab.

[image: Option in SSDT advanced publish settings to ignore column order]

You can also achieve the same effect by adding the following element to your publish.xml file:

```
<IgnoreColumnOrder>True</IgnoreColumnOrder>
```

Comment: Good news for the update. At present the update is exist, I will try it soon and give the result...

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to completely ignore Tables under: Object Types -> Application Scoped -> Tables

Or you can exclude the specific changes it wants to make due to the column order difference by unchecking the appropriate lines in the results window.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked. This would make Schema Comparison almost useless